# .htaccess redirect to https with conditions page

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/webservice|/api)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|swf)$ index.php [L]
```

I want all pages to be redirected to https, except /webservice and /api in those two I want it to open with both http and https.

In https requests everything works fine the problem is when I try to access http.

Problems

```
http://www.local.test/sub/pt-br/webservice redirect to https://www.local.test/index.php

http://www.local.test/sub/pt-br/api redirect to https://www.local.test/index.php
```

Any idea to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/webservice|/api)
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(\/webservice|\/api|\/sub\/pt-br\/webservice|\/sub\/pt-br\/api)
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/webservice
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/sub\/pt-br\/webservice
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/sub\/pt-br\/api
```

Comment: hello thanks for the reply, but still with the same problem, what I realized is that when I remove the `^(.*)$`
to
`RewriteRule https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`
works correctly, does it have any problems I leave without the ´^(.*)$´ in RewriteRule ?